# Sync project with private directory of bitbucket.org using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bitbucket

I want to sync my project with https://bitbucket.org/ private directory using Android Studio, anyone please tell me step by step, any plugin etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nHGCFKtYlw

You should already have git installed on your machine, and anything else is just like using git on the command line. Only difference is android studio will have some 'shortcuts' for you via the UI.

As of android studio 1.0 i dont think a plugin is needed anymore.